# Update snapshot with component variable values

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this in my component template:

```
<span *ngIf="!label">No label</span>
```

component:

```
@Input() label?: string;
```

And test:

```
component.label = 'My label';
expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Why is that generating this?

```
<span>No label</span>
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: not that span since I'm passing the label to the component

Comment: I guess you need to call detectChanges right after updating label